# Using pandas apply with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, apply

below I've tried to give an example of my problem. I not sure I understand the following error I receive right. `f['C'], df['D'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['A'] == 1 else some_func(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1)) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Is it because if in this case the 0 which is return when x['A'] == 1 is only a single int and can, therefore, not be unzipped? And of course any help solving this error would be much appreciated!
Cheers.

```
import pandas as pd

# A function that returns multiple things.
def some_func(x,y):
    return x+y, x-y

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5), 'B':range(5,10,1)})

# Example usage.
df['C'], df['D'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['A'] == 1 else some_func(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1))

print(df)
```

Comment: This seems very anti-pattern for pandas. What are you trying to do specifically? Because currently there are several vectorized ways to create these columns that would be more performant than this current setup.

Comment: @HenryEcker I've a really big data set and essentially wanted to apply the function only to some specified rows for testing while filling the rest with zeros. So basically I was using 0 if x['A'] != specified rows.

Comment: And is your function actually x + y and x - y? Or does this represent some more complicated function. I appreciate the attempt at minimising the problem, but often in `pandas` it's important to know what types of operations are taking place to make sure that the solution provided is performat as possible for big data.

Comment: You could select by index location `df.iloc[0:20].apply(...)` ? But again, this will likely be slower than any vectorized solution unless you _truly only_ need the first 20 rows.

Comment: no the function is much more complex. I am trying to apply a ground motion prediction equation to the data which has 11 arguments but return only two values as in the simplified problem. So I think I should be able to scale a solution to the example I gave up to my problem :)

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm not looking too much into speed right now. But if I use 'df['C'], df['D'] = zip(*df.iloc[0:2].apply(lambda x: some_func(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1))' now I get the error that the length of values does not match the length of the index?

Comment: How about having both conditions of ternary operator return tuple: `lambda x: (0, 0) if x['A'] == 1 else some_func(x['A'], x['B'])`?

Comment: Instead of `zip`, you can also try returning just 1 value from `some_func` and splitting it later using `.str.split(expand=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things.

One, as Parfait suggested in the comments, you return a tuple instead of an integer - `lambda x: (0, 0) if x['A'] == 1 else some_func(x['A'], x['B'])`.

Else, if your logic is more complex, I suggest you move your if logic to the function itself.

```py
# A function that returns multiple things.
def some_func(df):
    if df['A'] == 1: # Replace with your condition
        return (None, None) # Return a tuple, with whatever values. I suggest None, but 0 is OK.
    # Some elif logic
    else:
         return x+y, x-y
```

Then:

```
df['C'], df['D'] = zip(*df.apply(some_func, axis=1))
```